# PreparedStatements with DDL

Tags: sql, prepared-statement, ddl

I am creating a program to upload a bunch of database comments to tables and columns from an input file.

I started using prepared-statements but then quickly realized that wouldn't work for DDL statements.

I am essentially changing the sql statement on a table comment for each table name and its description:

```
"comment on table " + name.trim() + " is " + "'" + description.trim() + "'";
```

same for column comments.

There is no alternative for using a prepared statement on this correct?
Also, is this vulnerable to sql injection?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not so much a JDBC issue as a database issue. Databases do not allow you to prepare DDL, since there is not much potential for reuse. Most of the time, the reason you would want to prepare a statement is if there is reuse potential. DDL is mostly for one-off use, to set up the schema for an application. (Note my use of "most of the time" and "mostly" to indicate the most common use case.)

Also, in general, if you construct a SQL or DDL statement using string concatenation, you are opening yourself not just only to SQL injection, but other problems like syntax errors, escaping of characters, and so on. So, better practice is to have your DDL outside of your main application logic. Is this possible in your case?

Comment: Thanks Sualeh. I don't think it is possible because the input file basically contains a table name or a column name with a description. I just have the user follow the following format rules for the input file: use a + for table name, or ! for column, so:

+tableName - some description
!columnName - some description

I don't want the user to have to know how to write the sql, or write it for each table and it's columns.

Comment: if I can't use preparedStatements to prevent sql injection on a ddl, what would be the next best solution?

Comment: How about create a metadata table? Then, you can read the file into the table as regular data, using prepared statements.